# how to enable multiple select picker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to use this bootstrap select picker where multiple values can be selected, by default I want it to be disabled. So in order to enable it a button must be pressed. Problem is that pressing the button will not re-enable this specific field, other fields linked to it work fine.

Anyways the code not working is as follows any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 <form method="post" action="{{route('updateuser')}}" >
     @csrf
     <table class="table  table-bordered">
         <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">User Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                <th scope="col">Role</th>
                <th scope="col">Sites</th>
                <th scope="col">Created At</th>
                <th scope="col">Updated At</th>
                <th scope="col">Edit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            @if(count($users)!=0)
                @foreach($users as $user)
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type='text' name="id" placeholder="User ID" value='{{ $user->id }}' readonly></td>
                        <td><input type='text' name="name" placeholder="Name" value='{{ $user->name }}' disabled></td>
                        <td><input type='text' name="email" placeholder="Email" value='{{ $user->email }}' disabled></td>
                         <td><select name="role" disabled>                                                            
                             <option>none</option>
                             <option>Reporter</option>
                             <option>Admin</option>
                             <option>Super Admin</option>
                         </select></td>
                         <td><select class="selectpicker selectsite" multiple name="{{$user->id}}sitesSelected[]" disabled>
                             <option selected>  {{$site[0]->sitename}}<  </option>
                             <option> {{$site[1]->sitename}} </option>
                             <option> {{$site[2]->sitename}} </option>
                         </select></td>
                         <td><input type='text' name="created_at" placeholder="created_at" value='{{ $user->created_at }}' readonly></td>
                         <td><input type='text' name="updated_at" placeholder="updated_at" value='{{ $user->updated_at }}' readonly></td>
                         <td><input type="button" name='edit' value='edit'>
                         <input type="submit" name='save' value='save'>
                         <button type="button" id="btnDelete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userModal" value="{{ $user->id }}">Delete</button></td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach 
            @endif
        </table>
        {{ $users->links() }}
    </form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form input[type=text]").prop("disabled",true);
    $("input[name=edit]").on("click",function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").find("input,select").prop("disabled",false);
    })
})
```

As can be seen in the code this is a specific part of a table where the tables data is an editable value, the rest are input boxes which work fine but for this part doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated fyi: `name="selectedSite"` goes in the `<select>`, not the `<option>`. Since your `<select>` already has a `name` attribute you could remove `name="selectedSite"`

Comment: You aren't showing enough code here. I don't see an input named "edit" or a tr. Please also indent your code properly, there's no need to have 32 spaces at the beginning of a line.

Comment: So you want to be able to select multiple options at the same time? As in when you click one of the options, the option highlights and then you can select more. Then when you click the same option again, it deselects (or removes highlights)? If you could possibly provide an example from someone else of this same concept, that would be beneficial

Comment: I've included the whole code now hopefully this helps